# Django ModelForm not getting instance data

Tags: python, django, modelform

I have a model form that have multiple choice fields. using AJAX to update form choic fields upon changed field.

**Model**:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    CLASSROOM = 0
    GROUPROOM = 1
    HOMEROOM = 3
    STUDENT_RECORD_TYPES = [
        (CLASSROOM,_("Classroom")),
        (GROUPROOM,_("Group")),
        (HOMEROOM,_("Home Edu")),
    ]
    school = models.ForeignKey(School,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=False,related_name='student_records')
    grade = models.ForeignKey(Grade,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=False,related_name="student_records")
    record_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_("Record Type"),choices=STUDENT_RECORD_TYPES,default=0)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['school','grade', 'record_type'],
                name='unique_school_grade_record'
            ),
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return "Record ID: {}".format(self.pk)
```

**Views.py**:

```
def update_students(request,pk):
    updated_table=None
    student_record = get_object_or_404(Student,pk=pk)
    if request.POST:
        form = StudentForm(request.POST or None,instance=student_record)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,_("Student record Updated Successfully!"))
            #Getting data for view
            updated_table = update_students_table(request)
        else:
            messages.error(request,_("Invalid Input, Please check!"))
    else:
        form = StudentForm(request.GET or None,instance=student_record)
    context = {}
    # load form template
    context['form'] = form
    form_template_path = "components/forms/student_update.html"
    html_form = loader.render_to_string(form_template_path, context, request)
    context['form'] = html_form
    return JsonResponse(context)
```

**Forms.py**:

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StudentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for visible in self.visible_fields():
            visible.field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['school'].widget.attrs['class'] += ' select2'
        
        #the issue stands here
        #self.data.get('school') returns none even if its exist in form data
        if self.data.get('school'):
            self.fields['grade'].queryset = Grade.objects.filter(school=self.data.get('school'))
        else:
            self.fields['grade'].queryset = Grade.objects.none()

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'
```

the strange behavior drives me crazy because when I reselect the *school* it updates the *grade* choices normally (with no option selected!), but when I open edit instance form the data is there but *grade* field have no options in it!

Comment: What is `context['form'] = form` and `context['form'] = html_form` for?

Comment: @bdbd the first one is to pass the form object to rendered in template, the second is to overight the context to pass the rendered (ready html) as string in order to pass context as JSON